# Creating path based on geometry Points received using websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am creating a node js server which is fetching real-time data from websocket
I get 1 row of json string every second when it is triggered

I wanted to create a path from each row which also contains geometrical Point

```
For example, here's the data that we got: 

[1] {"tag":"a", "areaName": "areaEntrance", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010CD9CEF753E3A5E33F6F1283C0CAA1D53F, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:27}
[2] {"tag":"a", "areaName": "areaEntrance", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010C0C022B8716D9F43F666666666666EE3F, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:28}
[3] {"tag":"b", "areaName": "areaEntrance", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010CF0A7C64B3789F73F9CC420B07268FF3F, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:29}    
[4] {"tag":"b", "areaName": "areaEntrance", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010C14AE47E17A14F83FC74B37894160F73F, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:30}    
[5] {"tag":"b", "areaName": "areaA", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010C23DBF97E6ABCF83FB0726891ED7C0040, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:27.270}    
[6] {"tag":"a", "areaName": "areaA", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010C273108AC1C5AFA3FA245B6F3FDD4F63F, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:27.270}    
[7] {"tag":"a", "areaName": "areaB", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010CA8C64B378941FC3F068195438B6CE73F, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:27.270}    
[8] {"tag":"a", "areaName": "areaExit", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010C643BDF4F8D9702403108AC1C5A640440, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:31}    
[9] {"tag":"a", "areaName": "areaExit", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010C48E17A14AE470540BC74931804560A40, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:32}    
[10] {"tag":"b", "areaName": "areaExit", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010CC976BE9F1A2F0C40F4FDD478E9260640, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:33}   
[11] {"tag":"b", "areaName": "areaExit", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010C54E3A59BC4200C40643BDF4F8D970940, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:34}
...
```

**here are the things that we have to pay attention when creating a path:

1. It will start when a tag has at least two rows of data when entering areaEntrance
2. It will end when a tag has at least two rows of data when entering areaExit
3. A tag can go to the areaEntrance after it enters areaExit (tag can be reused, meaning, one tag can have multiple paths)**

   ```
    The goal is to have data like:

    [1] {"idPath": 1, "tag":"a", "areaName": "areaEntrance", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010CD9CEF753E3A5E33F6F1283C0CAA1D53F, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:27}    
    [2] {"idPath": 1, "tag":"a", "areaName": "areaEntrance", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010C0C022B8716D9F43F666666666666EE3F, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:28}    
    [3] {"idPath": 2, "tag":"b", "areaName": "areaEntrance", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010CF0A7C64B3789F73F9CC420B07268FF3F, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:29}    
    [4] {"idPath": 2, "tag":"b", "areaName": "areaEntrance", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010C14AE47E17A14F83FC74B37894160F73F, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:30}    
    [5] {"idPath": 2, "tag":"b", "areaName": "areaA", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010C23DBF97E6ABCF83FB0726891ED7C0040, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:27.270}    
    [6] {"idPath": 1, "tag":"a", "areaName": "areaA", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010C273108AC1C5AFA3FA245B6F3FDD4F63F, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:27.270}    
    [7] {"idPath": 1, "tag":"a", "areaName": "areaB", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010CA8C64B378941FC3F068195438B6CE73F, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:27.270}    
    [8] {"idPath": 1, "tag":"a", "areaName": "areaExit", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010C643BDF4F8D9702403108AC1C5A640440, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:31}    
    [9] {"idPath": 1, "tag":"a", "areaName": "areaExit", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010C48E17A14AE470540BC74931804560A40, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:32}    
    [10] {"idPath": 2, "tag":"b", "areaName": "areaExit", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010CC976BE9F1A2F0C40F4FDD478E9260640, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:33}    
    [11] {"idPath": 2, "tag":"b", "areaName": "areaExit", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010C54E3A59BC4200C40643BDF4F8D970940, "time": 2022-12-09 14:03:34}    
    [12] {"idPath": 3, "tag":"a", "areaName": "areaEntrance", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010CD9CEF753E3A5E33F6F1283C0CAA1D53F, "time": 2022-12-09 14:04:35}    
    [13] {"idPath": 4, "tag":"b", "areaName": "areaEntrance", "geomPoint": 0x00000000010CD9CEF753E3A5E33F6F1283C0CAA1D53F, "time": 2022-12-09 14:04:36}
   ```

   ...

**notes:**
idPath is used to verify where the tags belong to

Anyone has any idea how to do it?
It can be done in javascript or SQL

I tried to do it in javascript and SQL but none of this is working

I have no idea how to set the value on real-time data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you include the code you have tried, it might help us know what you don't know how to do. As currently stated, it's impossible to know what you are stuck on, and it seems like you're asking for someone to write all the code for you.